# how to show page content area in the front site in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm new to wordpress and i'm trying to create a website. i need display the content of the pages when corresponding menu items are clicked. my page.php contain

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
                  $page_data= $post->ID;
                  if($page_data=='116') //Home page
                  {
                  ?>    

                  <center><b><h2>WELCOME TO THE CLINIC!!</h2></b></center>
                 <?php 

                  }
                 else{    //for other pages

                 ?>

                  <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                  <?php
                the_content();

                 }
                  endwhile; ?>
```

but my content is not displaying. title is showing properly. what is the mistake in the code? please help me.

Comment: You have added content in the admin side content area?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
global $post;     // if outside the loop

if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {

    //your code here

} else {

    // This is not the home page
}
```

Reference link - http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags